# Manually merge two files using diff

Tags: linux, diff

I'd like to merge two files by doing the following:

1. Output the diff of the two files into a temp file and
2. Manually select the lines I want to copy/save.

The problem here is that `diff -u` only gives me a file lines of context, while I want to output the entire file in a unified format.

Is there any way diff can do this?

Comment: I know a lot of people like using vim in diff mode to do this, and there are a few plugins that make three buffer (old, merge, 'new') work better.

Comment: What's the problem? Just delete the parts of the patch that you don't want to have and then patch the file. Also note about [git cherry picking](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html). This is exactly what you want to do

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"I want to output the entire file in a unified format. Is there any way diff can do this?"

Yes.

```
diff -U 9999999 file1.txt file2.txt > diff.txt
```

This should work, provided your files are less than 10 million lines long.

Comment: This adds `+` and `-` signs in front of diffing lines in merged file

Comment: It is not a merged file, it is in unified diff format, as the OP requested, so the + and - are expected.

Answer (score 20):

One option that might fit the bill for you,

`sdiff` : side-by-side diff of files.

`sdiff -o merged.file left.file right.file`

Once there, it will prompt you with what lines you want to keep from which file. Hit `?` and then `enter` for a little help. Also `man sdiff` with the detailed goods.

(In my distro, these come packaged in the "diffutils" package [fedora,centos])

If you need to automate the process, you might want to try the util `merge`, which will mark conflicts in the files. However, that might put you back at square one.

Answer (score 10):

You can merge/combine the two files with diff using --

```
diff --line-format %L file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is to use the -D flag to merge the files and surround the differences with C style #ifdef statements.

From the documentation:

```
-D NAME  --ifdef=NAME
          Output merged file to show `#ifdef NAME' diffs.
```

You can use it as follows:

```
$ diff -D NEWSTUFF file1 file2 > merged_file
```

I usually then just open the merged file in an editor and resolve the merge conflicts by hand.

You also can use options to output an ed script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an emacs user, you can do this directly in emacs using the "emerge" tool:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emerge.html

Issuing `M-x emerge-files` will open an interactive prompt with a view of files A, B, and the merged file to allow choosing text that differs between files A & B, inserting part of A into B, and more.