# Merge 2 text files with differences marked as conflicts

Tags: bash, git, diff

I'd like to see the complete output of 2 merged files where each difference is marked in the same way as git marks conflicts in the files.
The use case is to merge 2 similar configuration files, inspect the merged file and and have visual hints to make evident all differences between the files so that it becomes easy to decide which one to pick.

I have already tried with diff and diff3, but I could only get the differences (with diff) or a fully merged file where only conflicts are marked (with `diff3 -m -A file1 file1 file2`). I've used git diff and related tools, but they all merge unconflicting changes, instead of marking them as differences.

The running environment would be a bash shell script, therefore it'd be nice to reach the desired output with common linux tools.

Example:

Contents of file1:

```
environment:
  base_branch: master
  branch: this_is_the_same_for_both_files
```

Contents of file2:

```
environment:
  base_branch: a_different_base_branch
  branch: this_is_the_same_for_both_files
  a_new_key: the_new_key_value
```

Desired output:

```
environment:
<<<<< file1
  base_branch: master
=====
  base_branch: a_different_base_branch
>>>>> file2
  branch: this_is_the_same_for_both_files
<<<<< file1
=====
  a_new_key: the_new_key_value
>>>>> file2
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63425/how-to-use-patch-and-diff-to-merge-two-files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902001/manually-merge-two-files-using-diff

Comment: This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63444) is quite close to what I need, but it doesn't use git style delimiters (i.e. <<<<< ===== >>>>>). I need to use them so that later on I can check if there is any difference still not fully merged.

Comment: I found nothing that does exactly what you ask. So I would write a parser on top of `diff -DVERSION1` to transform it to the git style delimiters. It's a pretty straightforward conversion with only a few logic branches, though it's true `sed` won't do since you might have to reorder some blocks.

Comment: Note that to get proper markup, you need a merge base version: the common version, from which both diverged. Using one of the two as the common base, as you did in your `diff3`, means that one side made *no* changes to the file, so *all* the changes must have come from the other side by definition.

Comment: A diff3-style tool will give you what you asked for *if* you provide, as the "common" version, whatever lines are in fact common to both inputs. That is, having seen that lines before `base_branch: master` are the same, and that `base_branch: master` differs from `base_branch: a_different_base_branch`, you would *delete* that line from your in-progress common-base-file. But this is silly: you really just want a unified diff with peculiar markers. The method of replacing `#ifdef` that @joanis suggests is one easy way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestions from the comments, I came up with this one liner which seems to solve my issue.
I would have liked to use constants for the markers in the `sed` substitutions, but apparently it's not straightforward to use variables containing `\n` with `sed` for mac os.

This code seems to work correctly even in docker alpine:3.8 using diffutils.
Other options (brew gnu-sed and similar) might not be easily portable.

```sh
diff -D AAAAAAA "${path}" <(echo -n "$decrypted") | \
  sed -e $'s/#ifndef AAAAAAA/<<<<<<< file-on-disk/g' | \
  sed -e $'s/#endif \/\* ! AAAAAAA \*\//=======\\\n>>>>>>> file-from-secret/g' | \

  sed -e $'s/#else \/\* AAAAAAA \*\//=======/g' | \

  sed -e $'s/#ifdef AAAAAAA/<<<<<<< file-on-disk\\\n=======/g' | \
  sed -e $'s/#endif \/\* AAAAAAA \*\//>>>>>>> file-from-secret/g';
```

Explanation:

`diff -D AAAAAAA "${path}" <(echo -n "$decrypted")`: outputs a merged text with '#ifdef NAME' diffs. I'm using AAAAAAA as marker name. Diff uses `#ifndef AAAAAAA` and `#endif /* ! AAAAAAA */` to surround text only present in the first file and `/#ifdef AAAAAAA` and `#endif /* AAAAAAA */` to surround text only present in the second. Note the `n` in the first `#ifndef` and the `!` in the first `#endif` comment. As all markers are different, it becomes easy to perform substitutions.

`sed -e $'s/#endif \/\* ! AAAAAAA \*\//=======\\\n>>>>>>> file-from-secret/g'`: substitutes the marker with

```
=======
>>>>>>> file-from-secret
```

As there is a `\n`, the substitution string is enclosed with `$''` which interprets correctly the new line character. However, the `\` needs to be double-escaped.